# Error establishing a database connection - wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress

I get this error. The connection details in the wp-config file are correct. I have only been getting this error ever since I sent the website files to my boss to put the website online. I also did a dump of the database to send to him.

Is it at all possible that something he did effected my local copy of the wordpress website? It doesn't seem so...but I have only had this issue since he put it online. Maybe did I remove my database by mistake when I did the dump? Can I check that somehow?

Does a database dump mess up my database? I was the one that did the database dump, to send to him. Did it move my database?

Can I reinstall wordpress as a solution and copy my website into it?

Cheers.

Comment: See you'r connection setting without knowing anything how can we help you. Add config det

Comment: @ali786 What are you asking for and is it information that would be dangerous to post online?

Comment: No you should not post direct details just put in xyz format and how you are trying to config when you make it live you need to do lot of modif

Comment: @ali786 It's a standard wordpress config file. Is it possible that my boss's version has made my local one not work?

Comment: Sorry can you specify, are you getting this error on the system your did the dump on OR the system you boss restored the database to??

Answer (score 0):

Check if your live server database credentials match with details in your wp-config.
your localohost credential might be different from server credential

Secondly check if your boss has restored dump database

Comment: Thanks. I have mentioned these issues to my boss in an email. Is it really possible that he could have affected my local copy on localhost?

Comment: Does a database dump mess up my database? I was the one that did the database dump, to send to him. Did it move my database?