# mysqldump cause database connection error?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, wamp

I did a mysqldump of my localhost wordpress website database and now I have "Error establishing a database connection" when I try to visit the site. Do I now need to restore it? I am using WAMP, windows 8. Can anyone tell me how?

I did the dump because my boss asked me to do it and send him the dump for putting it on his server. But it seems to have messed up my local copy. Any help appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error establishing a database connection - wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795770/error-establishing-a-database-connection-wordpress)

Comment: Its not a possible duplicate... its even the same person

Answer (score 0):

If you did it via an SQL server, I have no idea

If you did it via a file, try restoring it with

mysqlimport -u root -p db_name < file.sql

Comment: Thanks! I did it via WAMP which is local. Should I be in a certain location to do that?

Comment: I did what you suggested via the phpmyadmin user interface but no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding the following line in your wp-config.php file:

`define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);`

Once you have done that, you can see the settings by visiting this page: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php

Comment: Thank you. I am interested in doing this. Can you explain how this will help me to give me incentive to do it? I know my config file settings are correct for my database.

Comment: Just follow the instructions enter the define(..) in config file, then enter host/site/wp-admin/maint/repair.php....

Comment: Am I supposed to go to that web page of my site? I cannot because it says "Error establishing a database connection"